# given $\mathbb{P}(X=n, Y \leq t)$ find $\mathbb{P}(X=n)$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X, Y$ are random variables

let $a,b > 0$, $ \operatorname{supp}(X,Y) = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and

$$\mathbb{P}(X=n, Y \leq t) = \int_0^{t}\frac{(ay)^n}{n!}\exp(-(a+b)y)\,dy$$

my approach consists of finding the joint CDF then taking the limit as $t\to \infty$ to obtain $X$'s CDF and then hoping to end up with a well known CDF, however it failed :

$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq n, Y \leq t) =\sum_{k = 0}^n \mathbb{P}(X = k, Y \leq t)$$

then $$\begin{align}\mathbb{P}(X \leq n) &= \lim_{t\to\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \mathbb{P}(X = k, Y \leq t)  \\ &=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^{t}\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(ay)^k}{k!}\exp(-(a+b)y)\,dy  \\
 &=\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(ay)^k}{k!}\exp(-(a+b)y)\,dy \\ &=\sum_{k = 0}^n\int_0^{\infty} \frac{(ay)^k}{k!}\exp(-(a+b)y)\,dy  \\
 &=\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{a^k}{(a+b)^{k+1}k!}\int_0^{\infty} z^{k}\exp(-z)\,dz\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{a^k}{(a+b)^{k+1}}  
\end{align}$$

I think I'm doing something wrong because :

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{a^k}{(a+b)^{k+1}}  =\frac{1}{b} \neq 1$$

what am I doing wrong ? is it because we're dealing with a hybrid pair of random variables ?

Comment: ?? Why the *détour*? $$P(X=n)=\lim_{t\to\infty}P(X=n,Y\leqslant t)=\ldots$$ the trouble being that the formula for $P(X=n,Y\leqslant t)$ you are given/giving is wrong.

Comment: @Did I did that at first but ended up with $\mathbb{P}(x = n) = \frac{a^n}{(a+b)^{n+1}}$

so same issue

Comment: The correct formula might be $$P(X=n, Y \leqslant t) = \int_0^tb\frac{(ay)^n}{n!}e^{-(a+b)y}\,dy$$

Comment: ...Anyway, passing by the CDF was not going to make the problem disappear.

Comment: @Did yes I have to admit the détour was stupid, anyways I checked again and the problem was written exactly like this by my teacher so it means he did a typo. now the problem being ill-stated, should I delete the question ?